# I need to find a xpath, so that I can click on the next button using selenium

Tags: html, selenium, xpath

```
<button id="79436c61930112002b29d457b47ffbfa_next" class="list_nav btn btn-icon h_flip_content" title="" data-nav="true" name="vcr_next" data-original-title="Next page">
<span class="sr-only">Next page</span>
<span class="icon-vcr-right"></span>
</button>
```

I have already tried `getDriver().findElement(By.id("//*[@name='vcr_next']")).click();` which is unstable. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Use `By.xpath()`, not `By.id()` if you want to use XPath.

Answer (score 0):

You want to pass xpath and you are using selector id with xpath syntax. either use id or xpath .. you mixed both of them

You can use direct name instead of xpath

```
driver().findElement(By.name("vcr_next")).click();
```

If your id is unique then you can use id also as below:-

```
driver().findElement(By.id("79436c61930112002b29d457b47ffbfa_next")).click();
```

for xpath use below code

```
driver().findElement(By.xpath("//button[@name='vcr_next']")).click();
```